Deploy on Azure with database
I've created the project in ASP.NET Core MVC in that I have two separate function means framework in single project one is .NET class and second is ASP.NET Core 8 web application , this web app is referenced .NET class.
In .NET class, I created ADO.NET file where all database prop stores. And in the web app, the all website related content and code is stored.
Now I'm trying to deploy this project with the help of Azure SQL  database in Azure. It's successful and creates the database and gets deployed, but the table created on local SQL Server is not copied - which means it does not show in Azure SQL cloud database; only the database gets created, not the tables.

Can anyone suggest what to do or any tutorial?

Could you pls help check whether this case helped you? Per my understanding, creating data table and insert init data shall require us to write migration codes.

I used ADO.NET there is no migration included in this part. I doesn't use EF approach.

@Timir Bhingradiya please the code you tried in the above question

@Timir Bhingradiya share the code  in text in the above question and if possible share the code in the git link

The following steps to create a web application for managing student records using ASP .NET Core MVC with ADO .NET in Azure SQL Server and deploy it on Azure:

Create a database named "StudentManagement" and create a table named "Student" with fields for student information.

public static class ConnectionString
{
    // Azure SQL Server details
    private static string cName = "<your_server_name>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<your_database_name>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<your_user_id>;Password=<your_password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30";

    public static string CName { get => cName; }
}

public class Student  
{  
    public int Id { set; get; }  
    [Required]  
    public string FirstName { set; get; }  
    [Required]  
    public string LastName { set; get; }  
    [Required]  
    public string Email { set; get; }  
    [Required]  
    public string Mobile { set; get; }  
    public string Address { set; get; }  
}  


Create a "StudentController" with actions for Index, Details, Create, Edit, and Delete. Create a new ASP .NET MVC Web Application named StudentRecordManagementSystem.

public class StudentController : Controller  
{  
    // GET: Student  
    public ActionResult Index()  
    {  
        return View();  
    }  

    // GET: Student/Details/5  
    public ActionResult Details(int id)  
    {  
        return View();  
    }  

    // GET: Student/Create  
    public ActionResult Create()  
    {  
        return View();  
    }  

    // POST: Student/Create  
    [HttpPost]  
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  
    public ActionResult Create(IFormCollection collection)  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            // TODO: Add insert logic here  

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));  
        }  
        catch  
        {  
            return View();  
        }  
    }  

    // GET: Student/Edit/5  
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)  
    {  
        return View();  
    }  

    // POST: Student/Edit/5  
    [HttpPost]  
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, IFormCollection collection)  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            // TODO: Add update logic here  

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));  
        }  
        catch  
        {  
            return View();  
        }  
    }  

    // GET: Student/Delete/5  
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)  
    {  
        return View();  
    }  

    // POST: Student/Delete/5  
    [HttpPost]  
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, IFormCollection collection)  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            // TODO: Add delete logic here  

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));  
        }  
        catch  
        {  
            return View();  
        }  
    }  
}  


Create stored procedures for CRUD operations (Add, Update, Delete, Get) on the "Student" table and code taken from git.

public class StudentDataAccessLayer  
{          
    string connectionString = ConnectionString.CName;    

    public IEnumerable<Student> GetAllStudent()  
    {  
        List<Student> lstStudent = new List<Student>();  
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
        {  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllStudent", con);  
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
            con.Open();  
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

            while (rdr.Read())  
            {  
                Student student = new Student();  
                student.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);  
                student.FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();  
                student.LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString();  
                student.Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();  
                student.Mobile = rdr["Mobile"].ToString();  
                student.Address = rdr["Address"].ToString();  

                lstStudent.Add(student);  
            }  
            con.Close();  
        }  
        return lstStudent;  
    }  
    public void AddStudent(Student student)  
    {  
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
        {  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddStudent", con);  
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", student.FirstName);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", student.LastName);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", student.Email);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", student.Mobile);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", student.Address);  
            con.Open();  
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
            con.Close();  
        }  
    }  

    public void UpdateStudent(Student student)  
    {  
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
        {  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spUpdateStudent", con);  
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", student.Id);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", student.FirstName);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", student.LastName);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", student.Email);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", student.Mobile);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", student.Address);  
            con.Open();  
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
            con.Close();  
        }  
    }  

    public Student GetStudentData(int? id)  
    {  
        Student student = new Student();  

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
        {  
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Id= " + id;  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);  
            con.Open();  
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

            while (rdr.Read())  
            {  
                student.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);  
                student.FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();  
                student.LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString();  
                student.Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();  
                student.Mobile = rdr["Mobile"].ToString();  
                student.Address = rdr["Address"].ToString();  
            }  
        }  
        return student;  
    }  

    public void DeleteStudent(int? id)  
    {  
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
        {  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDeleteStudent", con);  
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);  
            con.Open();  
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
            con.Close();  
        }  
    }  
}

Local:




Create an Azure web app with .NET.



Deploy an ASP.NET web app to Azure App Service using this reference.


Azure:


This kind of thing is works but in my above project there is two seperate functions databaselayer and coding part my project health.., i already deployed like you suggested and it works find with database and its table but with above question it won't work.

Please share your code in text format the above question and also share the push you code to git and share the link.so I can help you.
